# Calculate the product ST, and infer from it the inverse of T.

Tags: matrices, inverse

S=\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
-3/2 & 0 & 1/2
\end{pmatrix}

T=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
2 & -1 & 4\\ 
0 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

I have calculated ST to be =

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

But i'm now unsure of how to continue? This is obviously a significant matrix but I can't spot the answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT : So $ST$ is *almost* the identity matrix meaning that $S$ is *almost* the inverse of $T$.

Which calculations produces that $2$? How can you change $S$ such that this $2$ becomes $0$ and the rest remains unchanged?

Change it and then calculate again to check it didn't modify any other entries.

Comment: Did it this way, thanks!

Comment: In that case consider accepting it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to do that, but I think I've managed to!

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of Gaussian elimination.  It should be clear that
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&-2\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
}
\pmatrix{
1&0&2\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
} = I
$$
That is, we have
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&-2\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
}
\;(ST) = 
\left(\pmatrix{
1&0&-2\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
}
\;S \right)\cdot T = I
$$